# Any good reference of mongoosejs?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

somehow, it is quite hard to find information  in mongoose official site.   I'm wondering is there any tutorial or reference site?

Also, the one particular question is, how to run update() in mongoose. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Mongoose for a project, and yes, the documentation is quite lacking. But here is the API, it helped me a a lot, just see what functions there are and how they work. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Also, I just recently switched to using [Mongolian](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian), even though it's more of just an access layer to Mongo instead of a fuller ORM like Mongoose. I prefer Mongolian, try it out!

Comment: yeah.. i m using mongoose.. but their api is too simple.  whenever I need more information, that doc gives me no extra help. :(

just take a quick glance of mongolian.  it seems quite good. but just don't know if it is stable or will continue to have support on latest node version.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, the one particular question is, how to run update() in mongoose. :)

You should be able to do:

```
Record.update({_id: rid}, {$push:{specs: uuid}}, callback);
```